# ParameterizedThreadStart with multiple parameters

Tags: multithreading, parameters, c++-cli

I have this code for a child form called by main application form that passes some parameters to it:

```
public ref class MyForm2 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
        MyForm2(String^ string1, String^ string2, String^ string3, String^ string4)
        {
                InitializeComponent();
                DoSomething(string1, string2, string3, string4);
        }
        //...
        void DoSomething(String^ string1, String^ string2, String^ string3, String^ string4)
        {
                //A lot of stuff in here...
        }
};
```

But since DoSomething() contains several other functions doing long loops and also updating my GUI controls (labels and progress bar), i want to move to move it to a separated thread so my GUI wont freeze. I'm trying to do this with ParameterizedThreadStart, but it seems i'm unable to find a way to pass all my parameters.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT - Thanks to evhen14! Here's fixed working code.**

```
public ref class ThreadParams
{
public:
    String^ mystring1;
    String^ mystring2;
    String^ mystring3;
    String^ mystring4;
    ThreadParams(String^ string1, String^ string2, String^ string3, String^ string4)
    {
        mystring1 = string1;
        mystring2 = string2;
        mystring3 = string3;
        mystring4= string4;
    }
};
public ref class MyForm2 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    MyForm2(String^ mystring1, String^ mystring2, String^ mystring3, String^ mystring4)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ThreadParams^ param = gcnew ThreadParams(mystring1, mystring2, mystring3, mystring4);
        Thread^ newThread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ParameterizedThreadStart(this, &MyForm2::DoSomething));
        newThread->Start(param);
    }
    //...
    void DoSomething(Object^ paramObj)
    {
        ThreadParams^ param = (ThreadParams^)paramObj;
        String^ mystring1 = param->string1;
        String^ mystring2 = param->string2;
        String^ mystring3 = param->string3;
        String^ mystring4 = param->string4;
        //A lot of stuff in here...
    }
};
```

Comment: It takes an object.  Any object.  Including one with as many fields you ever need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to create a class that will hold your parameters and pass an instance of that class to your methods. As a result, you will need to re-write your methods to accept that new class as parameter

```
public ref class MyForm2 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
        MyForm2(String^ string1, String^ string2, String^ string3, String^ string4)
        {
                InitializeComponent();
                ThreadParams^ param = gcnew ThreadParams();

                param->string1 = "blah";
                param->string2 = "blah";   //etc
                Thread^ newThread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ParameterizedThreadStart(MyForm2::DoSomething));
                thread->Start(param)

        }
        //...
        void DoSomething(Object^ paramObj)
        {
                ThreadParams param = (ThreadParams)paramObj; 
                //here use param.string1, param.string2, etc
                //A lot of stuff in here...
        }
};

public ref ThreadParams
{
  public:
    String^ string1;
    String^ string2;
    String^ string3;
    String^ string4;
}
```

PS: Don't have access to IDE, so you might need to fix some syntax, but the idea should be clear

Comment: Can you please provide a quick code snippet? It would be much appreciated!

Comment: Updated the solution. Sorry, don't have IDE with me. So, you might need to fix the syntax

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfectly working after fixing a couple of errors. Just edited my first post to provide fixed version of your code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why i didnt think about this before, but another solution to quickly do this without creating a new class to carry the parameters, is to create empty String^ variables, set their values right after InitializeComponent() and call them later in DoSomething(), without passing any parameter in the thread creation:

```
public ref class MyForm2 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    MyForm2(String^ mystring1, String^ mystring2, String^ mystring3, String^ mystring4)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string1 = mystring1;
        string2 = mystring2;
        string3 = mystring3;
        string4 = mystring4;
        Thread^ newThread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(this, &MyForm2::DoSomething));
        newThread->Start();
    }
    //...
    void DoSomething()
    {
        String^ mystring1 = string1;
        String^ mystring2 = string2;
        String^ mystring3 = string3;
        String^ mystring4 = string4;
        //A lot of stuff in here...
    }
private:
    String^ string1;
    String^ string2;
    String^ string3;
    String^ string4;
};
```